# How to set where border horizontally ends in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to set where the border ends on the right side (I don't want the div to cover the whole screen horizontally).
How would I limit where the right border ends?

```
    <div style="border: 2px solid white;border-radius:5px">
      Review By: {{review[0]}}
      <br>
      <br>
      {{review[1]}}
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
```

This is my current screen [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a width on your div.

```
<div style="border: 2px solid white; border-radius:5px; width: 50%;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/otkd3257/

Answer (score 0):

Give a width to the div. use below example

```
 <div style="border: 2px solid white;border-radius:5px; width:300px;">
      Review By: {{review[0]}}
      <br>
      <br>
      {{review[1]}}
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fixed `width` as suggested by others, you may prefer to just add a `margin-right` value to the `<div>` instead:

```
<div style="border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 20px;">
```